# send mail through spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I am creating spring boot application where I have to send newly generated response string for each transaction to user as a text file attachment 
so what will be the proper way to do this

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
@Override
```

public void sendMessageWithAttachment(
  String to, String subject, String text, String pathToAttachment) {
    // ...

```
MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();

MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

helper.setTo(to);
helper.setSubject(subject);
helper.setText(text);

FileSystemResource file 
  = new FileSystemResource(new File(pathToAttachment));
helper.addAttachment("Invoice", file);

emailSender.send(message);
// ...
```

}